# Spree 1.1.0 demo missing product images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm on mac osx, rails 3.2.3, ruby 1.9.3-p194, spree 1.1.0, rvm 1.10.2. ImageMagick was installed using homebrew and is on version 6.7.5-7

- First I installed spree `gem install spree`
- Then created new rails project `rails new mystore`
- To install spree to my rails app I did `cd mystore` and then `spree install`

The site runs fine but I don't see any images when I run the demo site. I also see that the `public/spree/products` folder is empty.

Any idea why the images were never created during installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that imagemagick wasn't installed properly on my system. You can check this by running `identify` at the command line. If it errors then imagemagick isn't installed right.

Once I got imagemagick installed properly I re-created the demo project and the images showed up.

It was hard to tell that anything wrong because the spree installation didn't throw any errors. So for anyone that runs into this problem, just check to make sure imagemagick is working.